Disconnected button state doesn't update when disconnecting, so Metamask doesn't pop-up when trying to connect back again
Context:
NFT Smart Contract/
React App/
State Managed with Redux store

Issue Description: When pressing "Disconnect" button state does not reset to initial state and Metamask connection seems to persist after this operation
Steps to reproduce:

Initial state: disconnected
account: null
smartContract: null
web3: null
Press "Connect" button, Metamask pops up, connection successful, state updated
Press "Disconnect" button, disconnect successful, state not updated to initial state
Press "Connect" button, Metamask does not pop-up, connection successful

Expected behavior: Connection should be reset to initial state(disconnected), Metamask should pop-up when trying to reconnect
What I've tried:
I've tried resetting state back to initial when successful clicking "Disconnect":
case "DISCONNECT_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...initialState, // Reset the state to initial state on disconnect
    loading: false,
    };

Removing event listeners:
export const disconnect = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(disconnectRequest());
    const { blockchain } = getState();
    try {
      
    if (blockchain.web3 && window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum.removeListener('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
      window.ethereum.removeListener('chainChanged', handleChainChanged);
    }
      
    dispatch(disconnectSuccess());
   
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(disconnectFailed("Failed to disconnect the wallet."));
    }
  };
};

// Event handlers
const handleAccountsChanged = (accounts) => {
  if (accounts.length === 0) {
    // MetaMask is locked or the user has not connected any accounts
    dispatch(disconnect());
  } else {
    dispatch(updateAccount(accounts[0]));
  }
};

const handleChainChanged = () => {
  window.location.reload(); 
};

Resetting state inside the "Disconnect" button definition:
<StyledConnectButton
                style={{
                  background: "#db3b3b"
                }}
                onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                dispatch(disconnect());
                blockchain.account = null;
                blockchain.web3 = null;
                blockchain.smartContract = null;
                }}
              >
                DISCONNECT
              </StyledConnectButton>

=> What would be the best way to disconnect the Metamask account and reset state to initial, so Metamask fires up when trying to reconnect?
I've linked the Github:
https://github.com/MihaiHng/GreekGodsNFT
